# Noticeable pause and stutter between page navigation

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, onsen-ui, crosswalk-runtime

I recently started uses Onsen-ui, and I am having a lot of fun with it.

I am using crosswalk for my Android application and this has gotten rid of almost every performance issue I've had. Pages scroll smoothly and everything is super responsive!

The only issue that remains is that there is a noticeable stutter between page changes. When I tap the button to go back (or to navigate forward to another page), the app will seem to 'pause' very briefly (similar to the 300ms click issue, but not the same because everything else is instantly responsive), then it will proceed to play the first one or two frames of the page transition animation, stutter again, and then complete the animation smoothly.

This is very jarring and really ruins the experience in an app where you navigate from page to page frequently!

I don't *known* what's causing the issue, but if I had to guess I would say that the first stutter is caused by AngularJs loading in the template data and the second is AngularJs actually processing the data once it is loaded (binding to all the properties - or whatever the correct term is! I'm new, forgive me :) ). Maybe the issue could be resolved by caching templates if angular supports such a thing?

Of course this is just a guess, love to hear if you guys had similar issues and would love a solution!

Note that this is tagged as Android + Crosswalk, but I don't mean to single out Android. The issue might be persistent in iOS too, but I don't have an iOS device to test on.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Do you get the same behavior without Crosswalk?

Comment: Hey Andreas, I have a Galaxy S4, and it is running 4.4.2. Without crosswalk the app is laggy all over so its hard to say.

Comment: [Here is a video showing the stuttering between page navigation. It happens between all page transitions.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97cmBXAjd-2NmFPX3RhRWVUa2s/view?usp=sharing)